# Is there way to disable tcp timestamps in macOS?

Tags: macos, tcp

I am using macOS Ventura 13.3. I know that in Windows and Linux I can enable/disable TCP timestamps via `netsh` and `sysctl` commands.

In Linux, it is the `net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps` parameter. macOS has the `sysctl` command, but I could not find `net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the exact same problem. Did you find an answer yet?

What is interesting is this:

On macOS Catelina(v10.15.5), when I was trying to set the max segment size(TCP_MAXSEG) to 1460 it failed, and with 1448 it worked. So I know it's the tcp_timestamp that takes the extra 12 bytes.

On macOS Ventura(v13.4), I was able to set TCP_MAXSEG to 1460.

If no luck finding an answer, probably next for me is to compare all the tcp system settings between the two OS.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/342355)